xdg-mime and xdg-open do not give the same results
I have installed an application that installs a protocol handler. If I run xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/foobar I get the application.desktop as the answer. But if I try to run it by using xdg-mime open foobar://test it returns gio: foobar://test: The specified location is not supported
I can fix it by manually installing xdg-mime default application.desktop x-scheme-handler/foobar.
Why does the output of the query indicate it should work, while the open does not work?
